# ios - send traffic over a connection (afnetworking or not) while waiting for response to keep it alive

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, nsurlconnection

situation:

- ios client that makes a GET request to a server and will save the response on a file.
- server that take up to 10 minutes to compute a specific request sent by the client. after task is completed, it will send back a large amount of data (300MB - 500MB).

in the http header I have

```
 "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5, max=100"
    );
```

but as far as I know, this header will only keep the connection alive for a timeout of 5 minutes.

The problem is that the server close the connection if not receive any data packet during its computation.

*The client for whom I work told me to send data while waiting for the response and to behave like a browser (safari for example).

How this can be achieved?

Right now i'm using afnetworking, but I can switch to any other third party software.

p.s. Increasing the timeout is not a solution because the server will close the connection anyway.

edit #2
what I would like to achieve is the behaviour of chrome that send [tcp keep-alive] every 45 seconds.

Comment: Get data from server in parts rather waiting for the response?

Comment: i can't do any operation server-side. Btw, there are 2 different steps:1) computation--> multiple sql query that can take up to 10 mins, 2) streaming to the client. the problem is in step 1).